# How can I check if a range between two time in h:mm format in SQL already exist?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

Columns:

```
sched_id
from_time
to_time
user_id
```

Example:
The user inserts new schedule of 2-range time. The user inputs `7:30(from_time) and 9:00(to_time).` I want to check if any range of time (between `from_time` to `to_time`) in my record is already existing so I can prohibit the insertion of redundant time.

Comment: What you mean by "check"? just check if exists or prevent new insertions/updates, if that range already exists ?

Comment: `SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE from_time = value AND to_time = value2;`

Comment: @OtoShavadze yes.

Comment: @VladimirLisovets yes that will work but I want to check the range between from_time to to_time exist.

Comment: it's usual intersection `start <= to_time AND end >= from_time`

Answer (score 0):

Use below query it will helpful for you

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM schedule WHERE from_time <= 7.30 AND to_time >= 9.30;
```

if the already exist it will return total number of count value.otherwise it will returns 0.

In PHP you can check with condition $count > 0